# How to get image and name of image from the index array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I set below codes for the the design. i try to get images and name of image form the index.`

```
function Link_Generate(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var links = '';
            var link = 'www.ski-roller.de/';
            var result = document.getElementById('wrapper');
            var code_id = document.getElementById("code_id").value;
            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                links += '   <div class="input-groups">' +
                    '         <input class="form-input" id="link_' + i + '" type="text" name="link_' + i + '" ' +
                    '        value="' + link + i + '/=' + code_id + '" placeholder="Generated Link "/>' +
                    '        <input class="form-button" type="submit" id="' + i + '"  value="Copy" onclick="copyToClipboard(this.id)" "/>' +
                    '        <label>Product Name:'+ i +' ' + '<img src="cr05.jpg" alt="cross prime" width="100" height="100"> '+ ' </label>' +
                    '       </div>';
            }
            result.innerHTML = links;
        }
```

`

Comment: And where is the `index` in the provided code? Please provide your question and the accompanying code in a way that the problem will be clearly understood by the audience you are targeting.

Comment: This is not a clear question. you might want to review the guide on asking good questions.